# Create Portable Class Library that targets all platforms (and publishing to nuget)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I have created the library [Staty](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/staty) that I want to publish via nuget for other developers to use.

I explicitly created it as Portable Class Library and restricted myself to very basic programming constructs. Now I want to publish it in a way, that others can easily use my library. I've set up my library as PCL with the following targets, which seemed to me as the most permissive platform-combination:

[image: Targets of my PCL library]

After completing the first version, I wanted to publish it, using Nuget GUI with the following nuget profile. I included the release-build files into the package under the `portable-net4-sl4-wp7-win8` folder (I've tried `portable-net45-sl5-wp8-win8` too, without any effect)
[image: NuGet Profile]

To verify, that my library is truly portable, I wanted to include it into another PCL-project, but unfortunately I'm only getting the following error: *Could not install package 'Staty 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable, Version=v4.5, Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.*

[image: Error when including package]

When adding it to a regular console-application, everything works fine. It also works fine, when directly including the dll into that very same PCL-project via References -> Add Reference ... -> Browse.

So what is wrong with the way I published the package?

Additionally I tried adding folder [dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611919/how-to-package-a-portable-net-library-targeting-net-core) and [net45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611829/how-to-package-a-net-framework-library) to the nuget package with the same dlls - without any success.

Comment: Check the list of targets, PCL is not on there.  You have to create a test project that targets one of those on the list.

Comment: Embrace .NET Platform Standard and .NET Core, https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/03/how-to-port-snmp-library-to-net-core/ PCL is no longer the way to go.

Comment: @Lex I will immediately change to that new project build-system once it is officially released and clear for me how to use it. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderPacha I rather say all the building blocks are ready (NuGet 3.x and .NET Core RC). If your library's dependencies are already included in RC1 or the upcoming RC2, you can use it right now, and no need to wait for RTM. #SNMP Library might have to wait further due to the missing API it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Change Targets* dialog, you are specifying *.NET Framework 4.5*, whereas in your *NuGet* setup you are targeting *net4*. Moreover, in the *NuGet* setup you are also targeting *sl4* and *wp7*. All in all, this means that when the *NuGet Manager* tries to match the library path in your *NuGet* package with the profile of your other PCL project, it is bound to fail due to incompatibilities.

Please take a look at [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY/preview) list to determine in which *lib* sub-folder you should place your *Staty.dll* PCL. (The list does not explicitly specify *ASP.NET Core* and *Xamarin* targets, they are normally implicitly accounted for.) From the list you can see that the target platforms you selected in the *Change Targets* dialog matches **Profile 259**, and the *NuGet* target for this profile should preferably be **portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8**.

(If you open the *Staty.csproj* project file in a text editor, you can confirm that the `<targetFrameworkProfile>` is indeed `Profile259`.)

Please change the *lib* sub-folder name in your *NuGet* file to *portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8*, and you should then be able to reference the *Staty* NuGet package from your other PCL project as long this other project targets the same or a sub-set of the platforms that the *Staty* NuGet package is targeting.